# I want to retrieve the data that is generated by the user but getting permission denied error in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Rule written for dummyOrders:

```
"rules": {
    "dummyOrders":{
      "$dummyid":{
        ".write": "auth!=null && $dummyid.contains(auth.uid)",
        ".read": "auth!=null && $dummyid.contains(auth.uid)"
      }
    }
```

Structure of dummy orders:

```
-LLKkP5GLMkMqy-OvFsY|3wvZGffGY5gUSKlFzhLw7hwXLEi1
    cemail: "nateshmbhat1@gmail.com"
    cid: "NKGiiChIqCdUcithC48mtuWkaAt1"
    cname: "Natesh Bhat"
    date: "2018-09-01T15:31:25.060Z"
    file_names: "JavaEvaluation.doc,"
    message: "Sample testing. "
    oid: "Order 230"
    status: "requested"
    xid: "ybfXhEkmCNbOuAN0XJYE8b84ix93"
    xshopName: "SIT Campus Xerox"
```

When I run the simulator in Firebase it is not giving any error.

I am trying to retrieve the data from dummyOrders and the rule which I have written above.

I am trying to access the data using below code :

```
var orderRef = firebase.database().ref('dummyOrders').orderByChild('cid').equalTo(user.uid);
```

I am getting firebase permission denied error. I am new to firebase and hence I need some help to understand how to retrieve the data which I am trying to access.

The dummyorder id is :

> -LLKkP5GLMkMqy-OvFsY|3wvZGffGY5gUSKlFzhLw7hwXLEi1

The UID from which the data came `3wvZGffGY5gUSKlFzhLw7hwXLEi1` and I need to display that data in his profile.

`-LLKkP5GLMkMqy-OvFsY` Is the of some shop to which I need to display this order too.

So for dummyOrder I have given the id as

> shopid|userid

Please let me know what is the mistake I am doing here. I am not able to understand why I am getting the permission denied error and how to resolve it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should add the rule as text; not as a picture.

Comment: Hi @JeroenHeier, I have added it as text. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note is that [Firebase rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters). So when you try to get data from `firebase.database().ref('dummyOrders')` it will check if the user has permission at that location. Because you have no rule for that location Firebase will use the default, which is `false`.

There are two possible solutions to this problem. The first is making sure you read/write from the location you have specified in the rules, in this case `firebase.database().ref('dummyOrders').child($dummyid)`. But since you are using compounded keys and you probably only know the user ID i doubt this will be the right solution for you.

The second option is using [Query-based security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules). With this you can specify what query is allowed. For your code in the question you will get rules that look like this.

```
"rules": {
  "dummyOrders":{
    ".read": "query.orderByChild == 'cid' &&
        query.equalTo == auth.uid" // restrict basket access to owner of dummyOrders

    "$dummyid":{
      ".write": "auth!=null && $dummyid.contains(auth.uid)",
      ".read": "auth!=null && $dummyid.contains(auth.uid)"
    }
  }
}
```

Remember that for query-based rules to work the query has to match the rule.